# I want to move all my "following" to a "private list" on Twitter

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to automatically move all of the people I'm following from my "Following" to a "Private List" I created on Twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [twitlistmanager](http://twitlistmanager.com/) could do the job, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: This will not do automatically. You have to _check boxes to add or remove people to your lists._

Comment: It didn't totally automate it, but it sure did help greatly. Moving them one by one is infeasible as it would have taken days, if not weeks, to go over every single Following and add him to the list. This took just the time it takes to manually check off every box against every Following; about 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to automatically move. You have to do it manually and for that here you go..

- Create a list
- Enter list details
- Add user to the list
- View private list.

Comment: That's the obvious. But when you want to move over 300 people, it becomes a bit of a hassle.

Comment: That is right. But there is no way to move automatically.